# Passar value do button para modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Preciso de ajuda no código javascript, sou nova e não sei bem a sintaxe.O que eu preciso é pegar o value desse button e jogar na label id_usuario, como faço?

```
<button data-target="modal1" class="negar" value="{{item.id}}" class="btn modal-trigger blue"><i class=" large material-icons ">clear</i

    <!-- Modal Structure -->
    <div id="modal1" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h4>Motivo</h4>
            <form method="POST" action="." class="viewform" id="formMotivo">
              <label id=id_usuario> </label>
                <button type="submit" name="salvar" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Salvar</button>    
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer"></div>
    </div>
    script>

             $(document).ready(function(){


      **document.getElementById("id_usuario").innerHTML = btn(negar).value;**

             });
```

Comment: Se não depende de interação do usuário porque não colocar la diretamente o `{{item.id}}` ? Ou pode levar outros `ids` ?

Comment: É um for, tem várias linhas da tabela, portanto vários ids, ao clicar no button daquela linha ele tá pegando o id daquele usuário

Answer (score 0):

O comentário do @Isac é pertinente, pois se não precisa de interação você poderia apenas usar `{{item.id}}` diretamente na *label*. Mas vou considerar que você apenas simplificou para a pergunta.

**Acho que você poderia fazer assim:**

```
document.getElementById("id_usuario").innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName("negar")[0].getAttribute("value");
```

Mas vendo em seu código você empregando JQuery, acredito que ficaria melhor se você padronizasse o uso do mesmo.

**Ficando assim:**

```
$("#id_usuario").text($(".negar").attr("value"));
```

**Snippet:**

```html
<button data-target="modal1" class="negar" value="{{item.id}}" class="btn modal-trigger blue">
  <i class=" large material-icons ">clear</i>
</button>
<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Motivo</h4>
    <form method="POST" action="." class="viewform" id="formMotivo">
      <label id=id_usuario></label>
      <button type="submit" name="salvar" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Salvar</button>    
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#id_usuario").text($(".negar").attr("value"));
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Obrigada pela sua contribuição. Notei que não está passando nada para o modal, o value está pegando o id correto, porém coloquei um texto qualquer para ver se entra no input mas nada. Acredito que seja porque estou usando o data-target, assim ele não precisa e não lê o código que crio abaixo. Se tiro o data-target não consigo abrir o modal pelo onclick

Comment: @BiancaC. Eu não entendi bem seu comentário. Editei minha resposta adicionando um snippet. Ele faz exatamente o que você perguntou, pega o atributo _value_ e insere como texto da _label_, sem é claro levar em conta melhores práticas, apenas segundo com o código que você forneceu. O modal evidentemente não está funcionando, precisaria adicionar a biblioteca que manipula o mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Como você utiliza JQuery, você pode utilizar no seu botão, um atributo do tipo [data-*](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp), transformando ele em:

```
<button data-itemid="{{item.id}}" onclick="OpenModalFor(this)"></button>
```

E recuperar o valor na função da seguinte maneira:

```
function OpenModalFor(clicked_button) {
   var item_id = $(clicked_button).data('itemid');
   $('#id_usuario').text(item_id);
}
```

Comment: Olá Bruno, obrigada. Gostaria de perguntar se sabe o porquê deste erro: ReferenceError: openModal is not defined

Comment: Este erro normalmente ocorre quando algo não foi definido. Verifique se você criou a variavel/função openModal. O JavaScript é case-sensitive, então, openModal e OpenModal são duas coisas diferentes!

E a melhor maneira de agradecer no StackOverflow, é aceitando a resposta, assim, sabemos que ajudamos!